# Comparing array values of just 1 array

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => West
                    [1] => 4
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => South west
                    [1] => 20
                )

        )

)
```

What I want to achieve is be able to compare `$array[0][0][1]` and `$array[0][1][1]`. So whichever is lesser comes first and I get the value. So in this case I know that 4 is lesser so I get West first then South west is next. It should be dynamic since we can get more than 2.

Comment: You've got a three levels of arrays here, so it's not entirely clear what you intend to sort. Are you trying to sort the outermost array (`$array`)? Or the array in the middle (`$array[0]`)?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried till now ?

Comment: As you said it should be dynamic, Please show your final array, which you want to sort, then after i will start working on it.

Answer (score 1):

This a simple example you can use :

```
$arr = array(
array("name"=>"Bob","age"=>8,"colour"=>"red"),
array("name"=>"Greg","age"=>12,"colour"=>"blue"),
array("name"=>"Andy","age"=>5,"colour"=>"purple"));

$sortArray = array();

foreach($arr as $val){
    foreach($val as $key=>$value){
        if(!isset($sortArray[$key])){
            $sortArray[$key] = array();
        }
        $sortArray[$key][] = $value;
    }
}

$orderby = "age"; //change this to whatever key you want from the array

array_multisort($sortArray[$orderby],SORT_ASC,$arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: I see so on this code, you are sorting the array by the lowest first, and then you can just extract it.

Comment: @Knide there are different types of sorts, for more info : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the depth of the array structure remains the same, and you only want the very lowest, you can use a simple foreach.

```
function findLowestName($array) {
    $lowest = 0; // variable to hold the index of the lowest entry.
    // go through every entry in the first array member
    foreach($array[0] as $key => $value) {
        // if this entry is lower than the 'current' lowest, mark this as the new lowest
        if($value[1] < $array[0][$lowest]) {
            $lowest = $key;
        }
    }
    return $array[0][$lowest][0];
}
```

Built as a function, so you can include it, and call the function, passing it the array as a parameter.