# PHP Sort dropping element of array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using this sort to arrange data in $arr how I need it.

It works very well, however, seems that it's losing the last array when there are more than 16.

I think the problem is with the data, but I've not found the source of the issue.

I when I use this array:

```
array ( 
0 => array ( 'race_order' => 1, 'heat_nbr' => 4, 'racer_id' => 620, 'heat_finish' => 4, 'race_time' => '120.00', ), 
1 => array ( 'race_order' => 1, 'heat_nbr' => 4, 'racer_id' => 645, 'heat_finish' => 5, 'race_time' => '120.00', ), 
2 => array ( 'race_order' => 1, 'heat_nbr' => 4, 'racer_id'=> 487, 'heat_finish' => 6, 'race_time' => '120.00', ), 
3 => array ( 'race_order' => 2, 'heat_nbr' => 3, 'racer_id' => 857, 'heat_finish' => 4, 'race_time' => '160.00', ), 
4 => array ( 'race_order' => 2, 'heat_nbr' => 3, 'racer_id'=> 1191, 'heat_finish' => 5, 'race_time' => '160.00', ), 
5 => array ( 'race_order' => 2, 'heat_nbr' => 3, 'racer_id' => 1269, 'heat_finish' => 6, 'race_time' =>'160.00', ), 
6 => array ( 'race_order' => 2, 'heat_nbr' => 3, 'racer_id'=> 723, 'heat_finish' => 7, 'race_time' => '160.00', ), 
7 => array ( 'race_order' => 3, 'heat_nbr' => 2, 'racer_id' => 245, 'heat_finish' => 3, 'race_time' =>'180.0000', ), 
8 => array ( 'race_order' => 3, 'heat_nbr' => 2, 'racer_id'=> 65, 'heat_finish' => 4, 'race_time' => '180.0000', ), 
9 => array ( 'race_order' => 3, 'heat_nbr' => 2, 'racer_id' => 269, 'heat_finish' => 5, 'race_time' =>'180.0000', ), 
10 => array ( 'race_order' => 3, 'heat_nbr' => 2,'racer_id' => 860, 'heat_finish' => 6, 'race_time' => '180.0000', ), 
11 => array ('race_order' => 3, 'heat_nbr' => 2, 'racer_id' => 226, 'heat_finish' => 7,'race_time' => '180.0000', ), 
12 => array ( 'race_order' => 4, 'heat_nbr'=> 1, 'racer_id' => 24, 'heat_finish' => 3, 'race_time' => '240.00', ),
13 => array ('race_order' => 4, 'heat_nbr' => 1, 'racer_id' => 1006, 'heat_finish' =>4, 'race_time' => '240.00', ), 
14 => array ( 'race_order' => 4, 'heat_nbr'=> 1, 'racer_id' => 625, 'heat_finish' => 5, 'race_time' => '240.00', ), 
15 => array ('race_order' => 4, 'heat_nbr' => 1, 'racer_id' => 1115, 'heat_finish' =>6, 'race_time' => '240.00', ), 
16 => array ( 'race_order' => 4, 'heat_nbr'=> 1, 'racer_id' => 1208, 'heat_finish' => 7, 'race_time' => '240.00', ), 
);
```

It works as expected. With the array included in the code below, I lose :

```
16 => array ( 'race_order' => 4, 'heat_nbr'=> 1, 'racer_id' => 1208, 'heat_finish' => 7, 'race_time' => '240.00', ),
```

I can't see a good reason.

```
//the insertion sort    
function sortArr(&$arr){    

    for($i = 0; $i<count($arr); $i++){      //loop that iterates through the array indexes    
    //set the current index as the current minimum    
        $index = $i;    
        $posOfMin = $arr[$i];    

        for($k = $i+1; $k < count($arr); $k++){     //loop that iterates from the current index to the array end to find the smallest heat_finish value    
            if($arr[$k]['heat_finish'] < $arr[$index]['heat_finish']){      //if a value smaller than the current assumed minimum is found, that value will be set as the current minimum    
                $index = $k;    
                $posOfMin = $arr[$k];    
            }    
        }    
    //swaps the position of the current index and the current minimum    
        $arr[$index] = $arr[$i];    
        $arr[$i] = $posOfMin;    
}    
}    

$arr = array (    
0 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 1, 'heat_nbr' => 3, 'racer_id' => 1191, 'heat_finish' => 4, 'race_time' => '121.0000', ),    
1 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 1, 'heat_nbr' => 3, 'racer_id' => 502, 'heat_finish' => 5, 'race_time' => '121.0000', ),    
2 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 1, 'heat_nbr' => 3, 'racer_id' => 1269, 'heat_finish' => 6, 'race_time' => '121.0000', ),    
3 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 1, 'heat_nbr' => 3, 'racer_id' => 723, 'heat_finish' => 7, 'race_time' => '121.0000', ),    
4 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 2, 'heat_nbr' => 1, 'racer_id' => 24, 'heat_finish' => 4, 'race_time' => '130.0000', ),    
5 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 2, 'heat_nbr' => 1, 'racer_id' => 1006, 'heat_finish' => 5, 'race_time' => '130.0000', ),    
6 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 2, 'heat_nbr' => 1, 'racer_id' => 625, 'heat_finish' => 6, 'race_time' => '130.0000', ),    
7 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 2, 'heat_nbr' => 1, 'racer_id' => 1115, 'heat_finish' => 7, 'race_time' => '130.0000', ),    
8 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 3, 'heat_nbr' => 4, 'racer_id' => 121, 'heat_finish' => 3, 'race_time' => '136.0000', ),    
9 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 3, 'heat_nbr' => 4, 'racer_id' => 620, 'heat_finish' => 4, 'race_time' => '136.0000', ),    
10 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 3, 'heat_nbr' => 4, 'racer_id' => 487, 'heat_finish' => 5, 'race_time' => '136.0000', ),    
11 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 3, 'heat_nbr' => 4, 'racer_id' => 645, 'heat_finish' => 6, 'race_time' => '136.0000', ),    
12 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 4, 'heat_nbr' => 2, 'racer_id' => 379, 'heat_finish' => 3, 'race_time' => '152.0000', ),    
13 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 4, 'heat_nbr' => 2, 'racer_id' => 17, 'heat_finish' => 4, 'race_time' => '152.0000', ),    
14 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 4, 'heat_nbr' => 2, 'racer_id' => 65, 'heat_finish' => 5, 'race_time' => '152.0000', ),    
15 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 4, 'heat_nbr' => 2, 'racer_id' => 860, 'heat_finish' => 6, 'race_time' => '152.0000', ),    
16 => array ( 'nbr_of_semis' => 2, 'race_order' => 4, 'heat_nbr' => 2, 'racer_id' => 226, 'heat_finish' => 7, 'race_time' => '152.0000', )    
);    

$n = count($arr);    
//loop that prints the array    
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)    
    echo nl2br("Sort Order:". $i ." Race Order:" . $arr[$i]['race_order'] . "| Heat Number:" . $arr[$i]['heat_nbr'] . "| Racer:" . $arr[$i]['racer_id'] . "| Heat Finish:" . $arr[$i]['heat_finish'] . "| Race Time:" . $arr[$i]['race_time']."\n");    

//loop that separates and sorts the racers according to their race_order    
$max = 0;           //variable that will use to determine the maximum size of race_order    
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){    
    if($i == 0)    
        $arr1[] = $arr[$i];    
    else{    
        if($arr[$i]['race_order'] == $arr[$i-1]['race_order'])    
            $arr1[] = $arr[$i];    
        else{    
            sortArr($arr1);    
            $arr2[] = $arr1;    
            if($max < count($arr1))    
                $max  = count($arr1);    
            unset($arr1);    
            $arr1[] = $arr[$i];    
        }    
    }    
}    
$arr2[] = $arr1;    

//destroy the current array    
unset($arr);    


//loop to combine the sorted arrays    
for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++){    
    for($j = 0; $j < count($arr2); $j++){    
        if(count($arr2[$j]) > $i)    
            $arr[] = $arr2[$j][$i];    
    }    
}    

echo nl2br("Sorted\n");    
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)    
    echo nl2br("Sort Order:". $i ." Race Order:" . $arr[$i]['race_order'] . "| Heat Number:" . $arr[$i]['heat_nbr'] . "| Racer:" . $arr[$i]['racer_id'] . "| Heat Finish:" . $arr[$i]['heat_finish'] . "| Race Time:" . $arr[$i]['race_time']."\n");
```

Comment: I have answered something similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771366/php-comparing-array-values-of-just-1-array/34771529?noredirect=1#answer-34771529

Comment: Why are you building your own sort function? Why not `usort()` with a simple comparator function? You're probably losing the entry because of a bug in your code causing it to get overwritten when you do your `$arr[$index]` and `$arr[$i]` assignments.

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work.

I don't see why it will work perfectly on on set of data and not on another thats very similar.

Comment: @Alex I appreciate it, but that's not what I need here.. I need this sorted on multiple fields.. And not in a natural sort order.

Comment: Why are you calling count() 54 times on the same array?

Also, is your bug here:  "for($k = $i+1;" ??

Comment: Because of the expected result. This sorts based on race_order then finish order. I lowest order each on each iteration.

Comment: in my test script I changed the second array, the broken one, to match the same exact fields as the first array that does work.  So the only difference is the values. Still broken. I'm really not sure how this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going wrong here:

```
// less than $max
for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++){
```

The $max is a value based on the count() of $arr1, You should do

```
// less than OR equal to $max
for($i = 0; $i <= $max; $i++){
```

Else it will never parse the last value, as what happend here. :)

Comment: Took me a while to look at this.. I've been sick all week and couldn't focus on the screen long enough to do anything.

Thanks